# azure service bus EnqueuedTimeUtc

Tags: azure, timestamp, azureservicebus

I'm sending messages through azure service bus and i'm trying to pick them up and read them within a `Logic App`.

I'm just having some trouble collecting the timestamp from the messages. My `EnqueuedTimeUtc` values look like this: 
**5247588462813888675**

I don't know what sort of timestamp that is. Has someone seen it before?

```
{
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Claims/Organization": "organisationon.crm6.dynamics.com",
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Claims/User": "",
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Claims/InitiatingUser": "",
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Claims/EntityLogicalName": "incident",
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Claims/RequestName": "Update",
"RuleName": "$Default",
"EventName": "IncidentChanged",
"MessageSource": "dxcrm-incidentcreated",
"CorrelationId": "{35ca6d32-e345-4692-aa1a-fafa65c4a657}",
"DeliveryCount": "1",
"EnqueuedSequenceNumber": "3",
"EnqueuedTimeUtc": "5247588462813888675",
"ExpiresAtUtc": "3155378975999999999",
"LockedUntilUtc": "5247588463817777224",
"LockToken": "cfa35891-9662-4a7a-a6ad-0be9383b4dc0",
"MessageId": "2ae22770dd134bfc9ae3bf15bd89f48f",
"ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc": "0",
"SequenceNumber": "11000023",
"Size": "5832",
"State": "Active",
"TimeToLive": "9223372036854775807"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation it's date time. Looking at the value, probably ticks.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage.enqueuedtimeutc.aspx

Comment: The MaxValue of a System.DateTime in ticks is 3155378975999999999  which is less than 5247588462813888675

Comment: @onmeyer can you reproduce this?

Comment: every time i get a message off the queue i see it, regardless of the original source

Comment: @onmeyer in your LogicApp, are you using the .NET client or the REST API?

Comment: I'm using the Service Bus Connector (V1 or V2) built in to the Logic Apps platform. i.e. I'm not sure

Comment: I've tried to reproduce this with .NET client directly, but couldn't. Could you try to use a ServiceBusExplore, get the message and share it?

Comment: this seems to be a problem within Azure Logic Apps. Are you working within that context?

Comment: No, that's why I wonder if you could generate a message in Logic Apps and export it using SBE. I'd try to take that and give it a try.